# How to make bottom to top transition page in HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I'm a beginner in code, I'd like to create a page transition like on this site when we click on a product to take us to the detail page: https://www.antennebooks.com/

I've tried to understand how it works but I can't, I'd like help to be explained how it works, how to code it, etc...
I've seen by inspecting the code that it uses AJAX js, but I don't know what it is concretely.

I've tried to do this but it's definitely not the result I want.

JS :

```
const redirectToPage = (page, animationClass) => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add(animationClass);
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location.href = page;
  }, 1000);
};
```

CSS:

```
.slide-from-bottom {
  animation: slideFromBottom 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes slideFromBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help and have a nice day :))

Comment: If you use jQuery you should be able to use `.slideToggle()`. Since you have this question tagged `jquery` I assume you're OK with using its effects.